# Eclipse plugin compiled in linux work on windows?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I have developed an eclipse plugin, which is compiled linux using maven Tycho plugin. But for some reason, I am not able to see the plugin in the eclipse running on windows. I am not finding anything in the log file.

As I am new to plugin development, Is there any difference does a cross platform compiled plugin would cause?

One dilemma I have in my mind is that, Does it really matter if I use windows based eclipse installation on linux, (as it is just a zip, extract it and use it) machine for compiling and building my plugin? Well, to me it appears that it does matters. I should use linux based eclipse for compiling a plugin in linux operating system.

But isn't this what is against java principle? Compile and Run anywhere?

Comment: The only difference in eclipse deployments should be the installer--most java apps can be distributed as a jar and go to any platform with Java installed and just work, and that's my experience with Eclipse as well.  If your plugin has any C, assembly or reliance on native libraries (JNDI) it would obviously cause a problem.  Java's write once run anywhere usually works, even for complex apps like Eclipse and Netbeans.

Comment: I don't have any C/C++ code in my plugin, its only java code that I have.

Comment: What do you mean by using a "windows based eclipse installation (...) for compiling"? Do you happen to use the deprecated -Dtycho.targetPlatform switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know, if you are using UI stuff inside that plugin then you have to export it for multiple OSes ... and you need some libraries from eclipse website to export your application in linux...

If you are exporting only the plugin then you need nothing... OSGI takes care of everything

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Eclipse packages are system dependent. To take one example, `org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86` would work only on a 32 bit Windows workstation.

Check your plug-in and see if you have any of these system dependent Eclipse packages.

If you do, you have to export your plug-in with the appropriate Eclipse packages for each of the environments you want your plug-in to run.

Write once, run anywhere is a myth.  Ask any Android programmer.  :-)